# facebook api feed picture not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-feed

I have generated the following url to share the page into facebook,

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=195106440518444&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.capella.edu%2Fcapella-experience%2Fflexpath%2F&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2Fdd%2F56%2F37%2Fdd56376f6bb3f69130ec3216a13ec99c.jpg&name=Capella+FlexPath&caption=FlexPath%3A+Your+degree.+Your+pace.&description=With+FlexPath%2C+you+can+still+build+the+career-advancing+skills+and+knowledge+you+need%2C+but+with+a+class+schedule+entirely+controlled+by+you.&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.capella.edu%2Fcapella-experience%2Fflexpath%2Fflexpath-trial-course%2F&ext=1519158959&hash=AeY6NpBp29iik5NI

While hit on the above link, I couldn't see the picture. And I know the picture attribute is deprecated. Then I have tried to use the other way,

I can achieve the same thing with the help of meta tag,

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/ye/r/lWB96Z8sFtt.png" />
```

If I have include this meta tag in my page the image will display.

But I would like to display the picture dynamic also same page I would like to use different image on different shares.

Please provide suggestions If you have a idea.

Comment: You have to use og:image. Just share unique urls and make sure they have the right og:image

Comment: also, don´t use pictures from the FB CDN as og image...

Comment: @Wizkid - I have already mentioned in my question, User A and B wants to share the url "www.xyz.com" to feed the facebook A want to use one picture while sharing the url and B wants to share the same url with different picture.
If we use og:image per page page we can use only one image. how can we use different image for same page for the facebook feed?

Comment: You can't. You have to share different URLs. Like www.xyz.com/?user=A and www.xyz.com/?user=B for example

Comment: @WizKid Thank you for the quick response. I wanted to check is there any way we can achieve this. Now I get it. It is not possible.